# Searching between 2 column numbers

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to validate in my webform i have 1 textbox and i want to search number and if the number i search is between the range of 2 numbers in my 2 column i want to show the data in the row of my table.

```
select * from SSPRequest where StartingSeries = '" + TxtSearch.Text + "' BETWEEN EndingSeries= '"+TxtSearch2.Text+"'"
```

Comment: Use query parameters otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Better yet, why not use Entity Framework instead?

Comment: SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from SSPRequest where StartingSeries = '" + TxtSearch.Text + "' BETWEEN EndingSeries= '"+TxtSearch2.Text+"'", con);

                SqlDataReader sdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    TxtTicket.Text = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    

                
            }

Comment: if the number i search is between the range of that number i want to show record found

Answer (score 0):

Well, drop a grid view, and then say have this code:

```
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSQL = "select * from SSPRequest where StartingSeries >= @Start " +
                    " AND EndingSeries <= @End";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtSearch.Text;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtSearch2.Text;
            conn.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

So whatever the sql matches, the grid will display. Your markup could be say this:

```
        Enter Start Number: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Style="width:25px;padding-right:25px"></asp:TextBox>
        Enter End Number: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch2" runat="server" Style="width:25px;padding-right:25px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" style="padding-left:25px;" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Looking at your sql posted, it seems a bit wonkey, and does not make sense. I would fire up sql studio, and hand code the sql with two range values and get the sql working, THEN AND ONLY THEN would I attempt the above code.

So FIRST get a working sql statement BEFORE YOU WRITE ONE line of code.